# MetaController should Observe three objects

Tags: java, multithreading, model-view-controller, observer-pattern, observable

I'm caught in a mental loop, or at least a lack of understanding of how to implement the observer pattern.  My intended `Controller` implements `Observer` **because** it's meant to, literally, observe the instances it, literally, controls.

The observed objects extend `Observable` **because** they are meant to be observed, literally, by the `Controller`.  What do I invoke `.addObserver(responseHandler);` on?  Another class adds an observer to the instance which, literally, implements the `Observer' interface?  That can't be right.

-----edit----- responseHandler is just a generic name for some unknown Controller

As an aside, is there a naming problem in this pattern as implemented in Java, or just a lack of understanding on my part?

Here's the Controller, which has now morphed into a Controller of a Controller:

```
public class MetaController implements Observer {

    private final static Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(MetaController.class.getName());
    private Printer telnetPrinter = new Printer();
    private telnetDataProcessor telnetDataProcessor = new telnetDataProcessor();
    private StringReader stringReader = new StringReader();
    private final ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Character> telnetData = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue();

    public MetaController() {
    }

    //the printer and processor each spawn their own thread so that they don't
    //block each other waiting for each other
    public void readPrintParse(final InputStream inputStream) throws SocketException, IOException {
        telnetPrinter.print(inputStream, telnetData); //populate telnetData in its own thread
        telnetDataProcessor.read(telnetData); //process telnetData in its own thread
    }

    //the StringReader just looks for particular keywords like "press enter to continue"
    //so that some phrases will trigger a response
    //commands may also be typed manually by the user (not implemented yet)
    @Override
    public void update(Observable o, Object arg) {
        //when telnetDataProcessor sends a String, send that String on to stringReader
        String cmd = stringReader.parse(null); //parse what and how?
        //send the command string back to the telnetClient
    }
}
```

Reading the [API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Observable.html) directly, unfortunately, is not illuminating for me.

This is an extension of an Apache `WeatherTelnet` [example](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/commons/proper/net/tags/NET_1_0_0/src/java/examples/weatherTelnet.java), a sort of poor-mans Netty to allow concurrent scripted telnet and live telnet responses for a simple [MUD client](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mud_client), which requires live processing of a non-terminated telnet data stream, as well as live output and user input.

Comment: addObserver(this)????

Answer (score 2):

Your `Observable` objects should `addObserver(yourController);`. When they change, they should then call [`setChanged()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Observable.html#setChanged%28%29) and then [`notifyObservers()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Observable.html#notifyObservers%28%29). You can obviously override these methods if you need custom behavior.

For example:

```
MetaController controller = new MetaController();
Observable observable1 = new Weather1();
Observable observable2 = new Weather2();
Observable observable3 = new Weather3();
observable1.addObserver(controller);
observable2.addObserver(controller);
observable3.addObserver(controller);
```

You can also give a reference of the `Observable` to the Controller (`Observer`) if he's also the one modifying it.

There's no naming problem. The `Observer`s need to be registered with the `Observable` so that it knows how to notify them.

Caution: If this is meant to be used in a multithread environment, you'll have to be careful using shared data in the controller class.

Comment: just in terms of English, if you translate your first phrase:  "Your Observable objects should addObserver(yourController);" what does that mean in natural language?  I mean, **where** do they addObserver(yourController)?  the observed objects don't have a reference to the controller.  I'm trying to go with addObserver(this) for now, see how that pans out.

Comment: An `Observer` watches an `Observable`. In code, this translates into an `Observer` registering themselves with an `Observable` so that they can get notifications. You can use `observable.addObserver(this)` if your class has an instance field reference to the `Observable`.

Answer (score 1):

The object/class that creates the objects implementing `Observable` should invoke their `addObserver` method passing the `MetaController` object (in its role of `Observer`).

I'm thinking that your `MetaController` could not really be an `Observer` from the point of view of the pattern.  Perhaps it's just the owner/creator, and from here your confusion.  Do you need `MetaController` to receive notifications from the `Observable`s?  Or a third category of objects?

I say this because as part of the question you wrote `.addObserver(responseHandler);` instead of `.addObserver(metaController);`.

Comment: responseHandler was intended as a generic name, MetaController is the intended controller.  although, as you point out, maybe it's **not**.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I came up with:

```
package telnet;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.SocketException;
import java.util.Observable;
import java.util.Observer;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentLinkedQueue;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class Controller implements Observer {

    private final static Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(Controller.class.getName());
    private Printer telnetPrinter = new Printer();
    private telnetDataProcessor telnetDataProcessor = new telnetDataProcessor();
    private StringReader stringReader = new StringReader();
    private final ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Character> telnetData = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue();

    public Controller() {
    }

    public void readPrintParse(final InputStream inputStream) throws SocketException, IOException {
        telnetPrinter.print(inputStream, telnetData);
        telnetPrinter.addObserver(this);
        telnetDataProcessor.read(telnetData);
        telnetDataProcessor.addObserver(this);
        stringReader.addObserver(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void update(Observable o, Object arg) {
        System.out.println("updated...");
        String s = telnetDataProcessor.getString();
    }
}
```